# Only Selected Curves Keyframes option gone in 3.6?

Tags: interface, graph-editor, fcurves

There used to be an option in Blender 3.3 and under to make it, so only the selected curves have selectable keyframes. But this options seems to be gone now from the graph editor. Does anyone know where it went?

3.3:
[image]

3.6:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was moved to the user preferences:

[image]

The project Animation 2025 is currently active, so expect many changes related to animation and rigging until it is done.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: The answer above is correct but not working in Blender 3.6.5
This option does not appear even after selecting in preferences and saving.

Comment: It is on my v3.6.5.

Answer (score 1):

I had a hotkey to toggle this setting cause I use it a lot, but in Blender 4 you have to manually re-add it through the keymap in preferences.

Under *Window*, add a new *Context Toggle* hotkey. In the *Context Attribute* box, select `preferences.edit.show_only_selected_curve_keyframes`.

[image: keymap]